# How use Marker Clustering Google Maps in Xamrin Forms

Tags: xamarin.forms

Maybe someone knows and will share how to use Marker Clustering (
[Marker Clustering Google](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/utility/marker-clustering)) in Xamarin Forms in the Android project.

I have a CustomMap class defined in which I have checkins. When I zoom out the map markers I want the markers to be grouped

[Lint to example](https://www.google.pl/search?q=Marker%20Clustering%20android&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi0y_L7p4LYAhWpKJoKHde9CbkQ_AUICigB&biw=1280&bih=703#imgrc=7qqj84CBagmm0M:)

I have create CustomMap class:

...

```
googleMap.UiSettings.CompassEnabled = false;
            googleMap.UiSettings.MapToolbarEnabled = true;
            googleMap.UiSettings.MyLocationButtonEnabled = false;
            googleMap.UiSettings.ZoomControlsEnabled = false;

            _map = googleMap;

        //restore last known position on map
        if (_lastKnownMapSpan != null)
        {
            MoveToRegion(_lastKnownMapSpan, false);
        }

        _map.InfoWindowClick += OnInfoWindowClick;
        _map.InfoWindowClose += OnInfoWindowClose;
        _map.MarkerClick += OnMarkerClick;
        _map.MarkerDragStart += OnMarkerDragStart;
        _map.MarkerDragEnd += OnMarkerDragEnd;

        _map.SetInfoWindowAdapter(this);

        _map.MyLocationEnabled = true;
        _map.TrafficEnabled = true;
        _map.SetMinZoomPreference(5f);
        _map.SetMaxZoomPreference(22f);
        _map.MapType = GoogleMap.MapTypeNormal;
        _map.BuildingsEnabled = true;

        var options = new GoogleMapOptions();
        options.InvokeMapType(GoogleMap.MapTypeNormal);
        options.InvokeZoomGesturesEnabled(true);
        options.InvokeScrollGesturesEnabled(true);
        options.InvokeMapToolbarEnabled(true);
        options.InvokeZOrderOnTop(true);
        options.InvokeLiteMode(true);
```

...

Comment: your link is to the JS API, not the Android API.  Try this instead: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/utility/marker-clustering

Comment: @Jason Thank you, do I have to download some a library?

Comment: I don't know, I suggest you read the docs